# mysql autoincrement is not sequential in innodb

Tags: mysql, auto-increment

Mysql autoincrmenting is not sequential.

when i was trying to upload csv bulk data it's skipping some of the auto increment id

The auto increment id is not sequential

The db engine is innodb & id is auto increment

example

```
   id      color 
    1      red
    2      blue
    3      green
    4      orange
    9      pink
    10     white
    11     black 
    16     gray
    17     brown
```

The id is not sequential.

Comment: Why does it matter if it's sequential or not?

Comment: And what is the problem? (Btw: it *is* sequential, it's just not gap-less)

Comment: I can understand the curiosity. But we need more input to help... How is the csv uploaded? etc

Comment: simple form upload by php application, then reading the csv data and all the data's are pushing into  one array  and inserting by insert batch  function within one transaction in codeigniter framework

Answer (score 3):

don't know about codeignitor and specifics of transactions, but i do know that "catched fails" in queries (like `insert ignore`) have the effect of NOT inserting, but DO increment the auto_increment. Look for your answer here. And for the rest don't bother 'fixing' this.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using MySQL newer than `5.1.22` this can be caused because of the InnoDB [locking strategy](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-auto-increment-handling.html) as Miguel Angel Nieto explains in [this blog post](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2011/11/29/avoiding-auto-increment-holes-on-innodb-with-insert-ignore/).

You can change this behavior setting the `innodb_autoinc_lock_mode` parameter:

- `innodb_autoinc_lock_mode = 0`: **“traditional” lock mode**, same behavior as before `5.1.22`
- `innodb_autoinc_lock_mode = 1`: **“consecutive” lock mode**, default behavior, this is probably what you have set, it's designed to improve concurrency and performance with the drawback of having *holes* on the sequence.
- `innodb_autoinc_lock_mode = 2`: **“interleaved” lock mode**, this is the fastest and most scalable lock mode, but **it is not safe** when using **statement-based replication** or recovery scenarios when **SQL statements are replayed from the binary log**

For a detailed information o the use of `innodb_autoinc_lock_mode` you can check the [detailed mysql documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-auto-increment-handling.html#innodb-auto-increment-configurable).